# Is there a Pythonic list comprehension that uses a for loop along with if else?

Tags: python, python-2.7, list-comprehension

Here's a list comprehension with a for loop to convert all characters to uppe case

```
string = 'Hello'
print "".join([s.upper() for s in string])
```

Here's a list comprehension to only convert the lower characters to upper case

```
print "".join([s.upper() for s in string if s.islower()])
```

Can there be a list comprehension that can swap the case in a string? Something like

```
print "".join([s.upper() for s in string if s.islower() else s.lower()])
```

Comment: Are you looking for `s.swapcase()`?

Comment: Yes, swapcase. But that's just an example I picked. Wanting to know if i can use a for loop, if and else within a list comprehension

Comment: `list comprehension to only convert the lower characters to upper case` - NOPE. It's a list comprehension that only takes lower characters and convert them. "Hello" becomes "ELLO". `if` is a filter in list comprehension

Comment: Also for Python's ternary syntax check: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you could do so using a list comprehension. Note that when you include both `if`/`else`, what is known as a [ternary operator](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html), the syntax must be as follows:

> `condition_if_true if condition else condition_if_false`

Hence in this case, you can do:

```
string = 'Hello'

"".join([s.upper() if s.islower() else s.lower() for s in string])
# 'hELLO'
```

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for. Syntax for using for loop, if/else within a list comprehension

Answer (score 4):

all you need is `string.swapcase()`